# Unity Ads won't load

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've made new project to test Unity Ads and my project has only 1 script (very simple) to show ads on click but it doesn't show.

## What I've done so far

1. Created unity ads account
2. Created AdMob account
3. Connected them to each other
4. Imported Unity Monetization 3.2.0
5. Running ads on test (this simply means even if my admob isn't active etc. at least i should get testing ads)

## Code

`script`

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class AdMo : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void showADD()
    {
        if(Advertisement.IsReady()){
            Advertisement.Show();
            Debug.Log("this");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("that"); //this will return instead (see image below)
        }
    }
}
```

`console`

[image: one]

[image: two]

**Any idea what might be wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the initialization step. I suggest to go through official [Integration guide for Unity](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/unity/integration-guide-unity?&_ga=2.171748448.1386564512.1568820580-232178765.1533241980#basic-implementation). Your script should look something more like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class AdMo : MonoBehaviour
{
    string gameId = "1234567";
    bool testMode = true;

    // Initialize the Ads service:
    void Start () {
        Advertisement.Initialize (gameId, testMode);
    }

    public void showADD()
    {
        if(Advertisement.IsReady()){
            Advertisement.Show();
            Debug.Log("this");
        } else {
            Debug.Log("that"); //this will return instead (see image below)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you dave, quick question, doesn't "test mode" check in services do the same as `bool testMode` ? why do I need to add it in my script as well?

Comment: I am not sure (I am not using UnityAds) but this is how they made it in docs. For safety I would use both while testing.